# Изменить название кнопки в searchBar ios 8?

Tags: xcode

Привет всем.

Подскажите, как изменить название кнопки Cancel в searchBar ios 8? Документацию читал, не нашел, спасибо.

Изображение кнопки, текст которой нужно изменить:

[image]

Comment: Предварительно включив навигационный бар в ViewDidLoad:
self.searchDisplayController?.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = true

Затем делегировать:
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        var barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Название кнопки", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "добавляем действия")
        self.searchDisplayController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
    }

Удачи)

Answer (score 1):

В общем, проблема и была решена, и нет. Если вам нужно другое название кнопки Cancel в поиске из-за языка, то можно локализовать приложение, и все будет нормально. Если вам по каким-либо причинам нужно просто изменить название кнопки, то можно установить пользовательскую кнопку, предварительно включив навигационный бар в ViewDidLoad:

```
self.searchDisplayController?.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = true
```

Затем делегировать:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        var barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Название кнопки", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "добавляем действия")
        self.searchDisplayController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
    }
```

Удачи. )